# How to pass a php array to javascript array/object with non-sequential keys

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a php array to javascript, but the array has non-sequential keys.

Here is a portion of the array:

```
Array
(
    [1812] => Array
        (
            [RecID] => 1
            [team_num] => 20
            [player_id] => 1812
            [name] => Brady, Tom
            [id] => 1812
            [tm_abbr] => NE
            [tm_id] => 9003
            [pos] => QB
            [active] => 1
            [ListOrder] => 1
            [lg_pos] => QB
            [NFL_pos] => QB
            [data_type] => off
            [fa_sort_category] => 1
            [lineup_elig_pos] => Array
                (
                    [1] => RB1
                    [2] => RB2
                    [3] => R1
                    [4] => R2
                    [5] => R3
                )

        )

    [15574] => Array
        (
            [RecID] => 1
            [team_num] => 20
            [player_id] => 15574
            [name] => Goff, Jared
            [id] => 15574
            [tm_abbr] => LAR
            [tm_id] => 9025
            [pos] => QB
            [active] => 1
            [ListOrder] => 1
            [lg_pos] => QB
            [NFL_pos] => QB
            [data_type] => off
            [fa_sort_category] => 1
            [lineup_elig_pos] => Array
                (
                    [1] => RB1
                    [2] => RB2
                    [3] => R1
                    [4] => R2
                    [5] => R3
                )

        )

    [16381] => Array
        (
            [RecID] => 1
            [team_num] => 20
            [player_id] => 16381
            [name] => Jackson, Lamar
            [id] => 16381
            [tm_abbr] => BAL
            [tm_id] => 9030
            [pos] => QB
            [active] => 1
            [ListOrder] => 1
            [lg_pos] => QB
            [NFL_pos] => QB
            [data_type] => off
            [fa_sort_category] => 1
            [lineup_elig_pos] => Array
                (
                    [1] => RB1
                    [2] => RB2
                    [3] => R1
                    [4] => R2
                    [5] => R3
                )

        )
```

I have tried this:

```
var roster = {};
roster = "<?php echo json_encode($roster, true); ?>";
```

But I get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"

The key is important to match the player id so I can reference it later in the code easily.

Comment: I don't see any jquery in this question ...or Joomla! for that matter.  Whenever you have pure php or javascript questions be sure to research at Stackoverflow before posting a question.  It just so happens that this is a mega-duplicate question there and would have been very easy to find.  For example: [pass JSON object from php to javascript in the same script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7879712/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap JSON-encoded values in quotes.

```
var roster = <?php echo json_encode($roster, true); ?>;
```